# Difference between different tensorflow fully connected layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

What is the difference between the different fully connected layers available in tensorflow. I understand that there could 2 versions: Object oriented and functional, but I was able to find 4 different layers in tensorflow:

1. [tf.keras.layers.Dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense)
2. [tf.layers.dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense)
3. [tf.layers.Dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/Dense)
4. [tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/fully_connected)

The documentation contains examples using all of them. I'd also like to know when to use each layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Keras is a deep learning library which functions as a wrapper over 'lower level' languges such as Tensorflow and Theano. It has recently been integrated as a Tensorflow project and is part of the code-base. If you are using 'raw' Tensorflow, you should not use this layer.
2. Tensorflow defines a functional interface. Layers and operations that are `lowercase` are typically part of this. These functions are used as building blocks when defining a custom layer or a loss function.
3. This is the layer you should be using.
4. This comes from the `contrib` library - features that are typically more experimental and volatile. Once a feature is deemed stable, you should use its other implementation (3). (4) will still be present in the library to maintain backwards compatability.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is a Keras wrapper function. Its functionality is same as 3. Checkout [Keras](https://keras.io).
2. Its a functional interface for tensorflow.
3. Commonly used.
4. Function under development.

Technically speaking first 3 have same functionality (same inputs and outputs).